# What is the statement of "How do you spell 'red'"?

Tags: sentence-construction

I think special questions can be transformed from statements.

For example, "What is his name" is transformed from "His name is ...".

As for the special question "How do you spell 'red'", what statement is it transformed from? Is it "I spell 'red'**in(or by)** "R-E-D""?

Comment: or "You spell red 'R-E-D'", which retains the pronoun 'you'.

Comment: @Sydney  In the sentence "You spell red 'R-E-D", both "red " and "R-E-D" are objects, am I right? If so, why don't we use the question word "what" (like "What do you spell red") instead of "how" (how do you spell red)which is a question word asking for a method or way?

Comment: @user3169 In the sentence "I spell red 'R-E-D", both "red " and "R-E-D" are objects, am I right? If so, why don't we use the question word "what" (like "What do you spell red") instead of "how" (how do you spell red)which is a question word asking for a method or way?

Comment: Perhaps the better equivalent would be "The way you spell "red" is R-E-D." If you want to use "what", you can but you need to rephrase - "What is the spelling of "red"?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{What} is his name?

comes from

{John} is his name. OR His name is {John}. The sentences are equivalent, with a subject and a subject complement linked by the verb *to be*.

---

{How} do you spell red? = You do spell red {how}?

comes from

You do spell 'red' {R-E-D}.

Or, without the word *do*, which is necessary for the question:

**You spell 'red' {R-E-D}.** -> You spell 'red' R-E-D.

'R-E-D' is not an object; it is an adverb, describing *how* (in what manner) you spell 'red'.

Another example:

{How} do you drive?

You drive {how}.

You drive {carefully}.